# JWplayer: Display image when no video detected

Tags: jwplayer

I have a website where I show a stream to my visitors using the jwplayer.

I want to know if there is a way to replace the video with an image in jwplayer when the stream is out instead of that error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1442607-example-a-custom-error-message

```
jwplayer().onError(function(){
​jwplayer().load({file:"http://www.com/errorfile.mp4",image:"http://www.com/errorfile.jpg"});
jwplayer().play();
});
```