# JWplayer: Display image on error without file parameter

Tags: jwplayer

I know there are several questions about displaying a default error image like this one [JWplayer: Display image when no video detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633386/jwplayer-display-image-when-no-video-detected) but in my case I dont have a default file to display.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
jwplayer($scope.jwplayer_id).onError(function(){
  jwplayer($scope.jwplayer_id).load(image:'assets/img/signal_offline.png'});
});
```

What I have noticed is if there isnt a vaild file provided the image doesnt work.

I have tried like this:

```
  jwplayer($scope.jwplayer_id).load({file:'', image:'assets/img/signal_offline.png'});
```

It just works when a valid file is provied:

```
  jwplayer($scope.jwplayer_id).load({file:'assets/video/error.mp4', image:'assets/img/signal_offline.png'});
```

So I am really new with JWPlayer, how can I do this if I just have a 404 error image? do I need a 404 default media video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no file is provided, the player will fail to set up.

What you can do in this case, instead of using onError() like you do for when there is a media error, you can use onSetupError() instead, when the player fails to set up.

```
jwplayer().onSetupError(function() { /* DO SOMETHING */ });
```

Maybe find the div where the player fails to set up, then add an image using JS?

Here is a quick bit of sample code you can use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template</title>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
    });
    jwplayer().onSetupError(function() { 
        document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = '<img src="http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/C4lp6Dtd-640.jpg" />'
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems to work in my tests.

Comment: This is a nice solution although I will try to avoid to manipulate the DOM by providing some error video.

I was just wondering if I could use the load method with just one image.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want to get into JS hacks, you need to load an error video, since the player needs a file setup in order to load properly. Np!